# Csh use external awk command as a valid checking condition

Tags: awk, csh

I have a Cshell script which I wanted to achieve something as below:

```
set RUN_STAT = `bjobs | awk '{print $some_line}' | grep "something"`

if(${RUN_STAT}) then
#Some command
endif
```

Here, is basically trying to `grep` certain task name and try to see whether it is still running. But seems with `${RUN_STAT}` variable, it is always empty even if that job(or that awk and grep command is returning me something) is still active.

May I know how do I use that `awk`&`grep` command as a valid check condition in Cshell?

Much appreciated!!

Comment: `awk` could search the strings with itself no need of using `grep` here. Also please be more clear in your question add sample Input_file and expected output file in CODE TAGS so that we could help you more on same.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. To be more simplified, I just wanted to know is there a way to make that $RUN_STAT variable capture the return stat of that awk command, it seems with such assignment, the $RUN_STAT is always a null variable

Comment: ok, so you want to check either your variable is having values in it or not?

Comment: See http://grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-26 for full explanation of how flow-control and if/then/else/endif logic works in `csh`. `awk` will have to call `exit $status` to generate a non-zero return code but that value is not emitted, you'd need to do something like `print "1" #error ; exit 1` when you trap an error in awk. AND this assumes that awk is the last command in the pipeline. Best to switch to bash or zsh. Good luck.

Comment: Much appreciated! Anyway I figured out a solution.

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk and you should never write scripts in C-shell (see https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not) so I'm not sure what to say in response to this question asking how to use grep+awk in a C-shell script except - don't!